# How can I calculate the volume of unshaped objects by image processing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, volume

I have to write the algorithm of "calculate the volume of unshaped objects by image processing" in **MATLAB** software

I have to write the algorithm that take many picture of the object as input, and calculate the volume of the object as output. Each help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As it stands, this is far too vague and broad. You need to do some reading, then some coding, then come back when you have a more specific question relating to the work you've already done. It sounds like you are supposed to be doing some sort of stereophotogrammetry

Answer (score 0):

If you have only the object and background in your image `I`,

```
O = im2bw(I); % suppose 1 labelled on the object and 0 on the background
Volume = length(find(O == 1));
```

The code above will give you the volume of object.

If you have various objects in the image and want to get one volume among them. For example you have an MRI brain image shown in the figure below on the left, and you want to get the volume of the edema (yellow part inside):

[image]

```
I2 = im2bw(I);
I2 = bwareaopen(I2,100);
I2 = imdilate(I2,ones(3));
bw = bwlabel(I2);
```

`bw` in the above code will give you the figure on the right. As you can see there are three parts that are labelled with 1 - 3. Then,

```
stats=regionprops(bw,'PixelIdxList');
length(stats(1).PixelIdxList)
length(stats(2).PixelIdxList)
length(stats(3).PixelIdxList)
```

will give you 14455, 404, 9632 respectively. The yellow part in the left image is labelled 3 on the right. So the volume of the object is 9632.